# Parse PDF for Form Titles

Tags: ios, parsing, pdf

I want parse pdf for form field names and types. Is it possible? Because when I tried one PDF, it gave me some strange characters e.g.:

...
?õ»â¢_¸ðO´×¢É]Ì|BQÔQClã(¢dVò¶~?ýg?þª í

pÅ2ÞÎÉÍ??Ú?wÈ³.?d;k)*lÙ´¸(ò!ú©=ià??d?éPØ¶2Èåäý?»p?nÜÈûÏ??M

õl:`Þ°Ã3£BíTCy5 ?ð?tN¿7fDõK

±¦?i¹vü~»X?s÷A~Ôê±4?ÕµX±¤?

...

Where could be the problem? I used tool http://support.persits.com/pdf/demo_formfields.asp and pdf https://www.drsr.sk//priznania/dpfoa2010.pdf

I want make some parser for iOS. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF parsing on iOS, use the [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html) API.

For an example of an app which makes use of this API, see this [reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader).

To extract the specific information you're interested in, you will need to read the PDF document structure [specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and figure out which dictionaries it's in (or, if you're lucky find some sample code).

Comment: The reader is interesting, but I wanted to extract form fields from structure of PDF itself. I wanted some library that can parse that structure and give me field types, constraints and labels. Anyway thank you.

Comment: The Quartz API *does* allow you to extract form fields - it's just that you will have to figure out by yourself the correct dictionaries names to extract. I agree it would be nice to functions which would do this last part for you :)

Comment: Oh, I thought that Quartz have something to do with graphics and rendering PDF instead of parsing structure :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I looked into reference and found something. I was able to open PDF and make some CGPDFDictionaryRef but I am stuck at that point. This is my code:

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("simple_form.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
//CFRelease(pdfURL);

int k;
CGPDFPageRef myPage;

NSInteger numOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (myDocument);
for (k = 0; k < numOfPages; k++) {
  myPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (myDocument, k + 1 );
  CGPDFDictionaryRef ref = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(myPage); //what at this point?
  CGPDFPageRelease (myPage);
}
```

I`d like to have something similar to Figure 14-1 [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html)